# useState with onClick in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, onclick, styles

I'm trying to set my divs className dynamically, but it only updates when I click the second time on my div:

```
const [ clicked, setClicked ] = useState<string>('');

const returnContent = (
  <div
    className={`d-flex pt-1 custom-table-row ${clicked}`}
    onClick={() => setClicked('clicked')}
  >
    {content}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: returnContent? why not just return?

Comment: can you post the whole component? Do you return the <div> you have here?

Comment: it's rendered in the tsx "return" part at the end of the code... sorry

Comment: I have created a codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-mendel-1xu90?file=/src/App.js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the `useState` code inside your `returnContent` block of code.
Take a look at the snippet

```js
// import React, { useState } from 'react'

/*
* @returns {String}
*/
// cx({ myclass: true, mystyle: 3, bar: 0, foo: undefined }) /=> "myclass mystyle"
const cx = classes => Object
  .keys(classes)
  .filter(k => !!classes[k])
  .join(' ')


// Component
const App = (props) => {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = React.useState(false)
  
  return (
    <div id='divToClick' className={cx({ clicked })} onClick={() => setClicked(isClicked => !isClicked)}>
      Click Me {clicked && 'again'}
    </div>
  )
}


// React DOM
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
/* Page Style */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: --apple-system, 'Roboto', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
}

#root {
  padding: 25px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}


/* Rendered component style */
#divToClick {
  background: black;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: .5em;
}

#divToClick.clicked {
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```